# How to access the servlet context from a different application in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

We have two different applications deployed on different Tomcat servers. One application is developed using JSF, Spring + hibernate technologies and the other one is developed using plain Java EE Servlets technology.

The JSF application interacts with the Servlet application to fetch the data and calls the servlet using the following way from the JSF application:

```
URL url = new URL(“urlofservlets”); // http://application.com/servletName

URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

BufferedReader in = null;

try {    
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));    
    in.readLine();    
}    
catch(Exception ex) {    
  logger.error(ex);    
}
```

Now the servlet response is displayed in the JSF page using the following way:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="report_preview_modal_panel" moveable="false" minWidth="1200" minHeight="450">    
    <iframe id="report_preview_iframe" frameborder="2" src="${(rportController.reportPreviewUrl == null) ? 'about:blank' : reportController.reportPreviewUrl}" style="width:100%;height:390px;"></iframe>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

The iFrame tag will display the HTTP response from the servlets (using the servlet's URL i.e. `reportController.reportPreviewUrl` contains the servlet URL).

Now what we want to implement is, instead of loading the http response data from the servlets in iFrame tag, the data must be shown in the JSF Data table. But we need to get the data from the servlet response in such a way that JSF can access the servlet application context.

So, we can store the bean on the servlet session attribute and access the same in the JSF application to display the data in the JSF data table. Is this possible? How we can get the context of the different application (i.e. here from servlet) in the JSF application. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "Different application" is very ambiguous. Are you talking about 1 WAR file or 2 WAR files? If 2 WAR files, are they deployed to same servletcontainer?

Comment: Yes... the two applications have their separate WAR files. But deployed on the different tomcat servers on two different machines and have two different containers. The JSF uses FacesContext and Servlet app uses ServletContext

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access the ServletContext from another server. However, you can certainly expose objects in another application in a variety of ways:

- Create an EJB in the "servlet app" and access it from the "JSF app" using the remote interface.
- Create a web service using something like REST or SOAP. If you use JAXB annotations, this can be done quite cleanly.
- Have the servlet serialize the objects, return them in a similar manner to what you did above, and deserialize them in the JSF app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jeremiah...we will try the above approaches that you had suggested...